# Clojure Emacs etags

Tags: emacs, clojure

I want to index clojure files, using etags so that i can use Emacs's tag functionality.
But etags does not recognize clojure functions. is it possible to extend etags to include clojure definitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on http://nakkaya.com/2009/12/13/getting-etags-to-index-clojure-files/

the following command is all on one line

`find . \! -name '.*' -name '*.clj' | xargs etags --regex='/[ \t\(]*def[a-z]* \([a-z-!]+\)/\1/' --regex='/[ \t\(]*ns \([a-z.]+\)/\1/'`

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source, it seems that you would just have to run `etags` using the `--language=lisp` flag, since the Lisp recognizer looks for the string 'def'.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to modify `etags` so that it can recognize Clojure and produce a tags file for it. [Here is the source of `etags` in htmlized form](http://csourcesearch.net/c/fidA88701A805498CB9344F654304FFDAE913100988.aspx?s=sort#L313). It doesn't look like it would be that difficult or long a job to do. Here are the rules for recognizing Python as an example:

```
/*
* Python support
* Look for /^[\t]*def[ \t\n]+[^ \t\n(:]+/ or /^class[ \t\n]+[^ \t\n(:]+/
* Idea by Eric S. Raymond <esr@thyrsus.com> (1997)
* More ideas by seb bacon <seb@jamkit.com> (2002)
*/
static void
Python_functions (inf)
     FILE *inf;
{
  register char *cp;

   LOOP_ON_INPUT_LINES (inf, lb, cp)
     {
      cp = skip_spaces (cp);
      if (LOOKING_AT (cp, "def") || LOOKING_AT (cp, "class"))
        {
      char *name = cp;
      while (!notinname (*cp) && *cp != ':')
        cp++;
      make_tag (name, cp - name, TRUE,
            lb.buffer, cp - lb.buffer + 1, lineno, linecharno);
     }
   }
}
```

The Lisp support is a little more involved:

```
/*
 * Lisp tag functions
 *  look for (def or (DEF, quote or QUOTE
 */

static void L_getit __P((void));

static void
 L_getit ()
 {
  if (*dbp == '\'')     /* Skip prefix quote */
    dbp++;
  else if (*dbp == '(')
  {
    dbp++;
    /* Try to skip "(quote " */
    if (!LOOKING_AT (dbp, "quote") && !LOOKING_AT (dbp, "QUOTE"))
      /* Ok, then skip "(" before name in (defstruct (foo)) */
      dbp = skip_spaces (dbp);
  }
  get_tag (dbp, NULL);
}

static void
Lisp_functions (inf)
     FILE *inf;
{
  LOOP_ON_INPUT_LINES (inf, lb, dbp)
    {
      if (dbp[0] != '(')
    continue;

      if (strneq (dbp+1, "def", 3) || strneq (dbp+1, "DEF", 3))
    {
      dbp = skip_non_spaces (dbp);
      dbp = skip_spaces (dbp);
      L_getit ();
    }
      else
    {
          /* Check for (foo::defmumble name-defined ... */
      do
        dbp++;
      while (!notinname (*dbp) && *dbp != ':');
      if (*dbp == ':')
        {
          do
            dbp++;
          while (*dbp == ':');

              if (strneq (dbp, "def", 3) || strneq (dbp, "DEF", 3))
                {
                  dbp = skip_non_spaces (dbp);
                  dbp = skip_spaces (dbp);
                  L_getit ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To improve on miner49's answer:

I have this in my .emacs (note slight change in regex, ctags was yelling about
having "-" in the middle of the regex when not used to specify a range)

```
 ; Recursively generate tags for all *.clj files, 
 ; creating tags for def* and namespaces
(defun create-clj-tags (dir-name)
 "Create tags file."
 (interactive "Directory: ")
 (shell-command
  (format "%s  --langdef=Clojure --langmap=Clojure:.clj --regex-Clojure='/[ \t\(]*def[a-z]* \([a-z!-]+\)/\1/'  --regex-Clojure='/[ \t\(]*ns \([a-z.]+\)/\1/' -f %s/TAGS -e -R %s" path-to-ctags dir-name (directory-file-name dir-name)))
 )
```

Another obstacle was that on my box slime overrides M-. to use it's own lookup function rather then find-tag, and that function failed to work properly. e it's own lookup function rather then find-tag, and that function failed to work properly. you can invoke find-tag seperatley
to find tags from the TAG file, but the builtin function jumps to the source of builtin functions when connected to a slime/swank server , which is pretty neat.
my elisp skills failed to consolidate the two. slime expects find-tag to return nil if it fails which seems not to happen, so the following

```
(add-hook 'slime-edit-definition-hooks 'find-tag)
```

brings back TAGS based searches, but destroys swank-server searches.

Answer (score 2):

@miller49r's answer wan really nice. I modified it a bit to recognize metadata and some more acceptable clojure symbol chalaracters:

```
find . \! -name '.*' -name '*.clj' \
    | xargs etags \
    --regex='/[ \t\(]*def[a-zA-Z!$%&*+\-.\/:<=>?@^_~]*[ \n\t]+\(\^{[^}]*}[ \n\t]+\|\)\([a-zA-Z!$%&*+\-.\/:<=>?@^_~]+\)/\2/s' \
    --regex='/[ \t\(]*ns \([a-z.]+\)/\1/'
```